# Overlapping two boxes

Tags: css, overlap, box

I have been trying to have two boxes in CSS, one in the upper right hand corner of the other. I have been trying to nest divs and use relative positioning but I cannot figure out how to do it. Can someone help me? (Not using z index)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this. Using flexBox to align them and giving a negative margin to second box.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.first{
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
.second{
  margin-top:-50%;
  height: 5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <div class="first"></div>
      <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Based on Marcos answer i think i understand you wrong.

Here is a simple way get the result that you want. You can use `position:relative` to parent and `position: absolute` to child item. Then you can move child element inside. `top:0;` will take you to top corner and `right:0;` will take you to right corner.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
}

.parent{
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  background-color: tomato;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
  width: 5rem;
  height: 5rem;
  background-color: aqua;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly that you want one box to be inside the other, you can achieve this using `position: relative` and moving the inner box using `top`, `right`, `left` and `bottom`.

I recommend diving in to the [MDN page for CSS position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) for more information.

```css
.box1, .box2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

.box1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.box2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: -100px;
  left: -100px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class='box1'></div>
<div class='box2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spontaneously, I can think of two possibilities. 1) Work with 'position' or 2) work with 'margin'.

**here an example with margin in combination flexbox;**

```css
.w {
  background-color: lightgray;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 20px;
}

.a, .b {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.a {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.b {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="w">
  <div class="a">A</div>
  <div class="b">B</div>
</div>
```